# htaccess redirect site/subfolder to site/subfolder.php

Tags: .htaccess, web

i have the following .htaccess file

```
#~ Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

#~ Re-write urls for PHP documents.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#~ redirect site/subfolder to site/subfolder.php
RewriteCond %{REQUESTFILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

This changes the urls from site.com/something.php to site.com/something
but the last bit doesnt work as intended, i have a folder site.com/myfolder/ and when user goes to "site.com/myfolder" i want to have site.com/myfolder.php displayed instead of the actual folder. This actually happens now, but it treads the page as if it is in the subfolder instead in the root so all relative urls are broken, anyone can think of an solution to this?

**My final solution:**
[Edit] posted complete script below.

Answer (score 0):

The final issue that came up after using DirectorySlash Off was that the site was only accessible trough http://mysite.com/ and not http://mysite.com

So you need to fix that with a simple error redirect

So the complete solution is this:

```
#~ Turn off displaying index for folders and give a error 403 instead.
Options -Indexes

#~ Set the error page to the top folder of your website ending with a slash, use a http adres to make it act like a re-direct.
ErrorDocument 403 http://mysite.com/

#~ Set default page for folders.
DirectoryIndex index.php

#~ Turn off directory slashes.
DirectorySlash Off

#~ Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

#~ Re-write urls for PHP documents.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `/myfolder` and not `/myfolder/` to be rewritten into `myfolder.php`? Try to use this code in your `.htaccess` hidden file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1.php
```

But if you want to redirect it and not to be rewritten, then just add *(a space and a)* `[R]` flag after the `.php` on the code. Or else?

Comment: No, i just wanted all php urls rewritten, which is impossible for the php files that have identical names as a folder cause the server prioritizes the folders and ignores the files so it puts a trailing slash.
Hence the only solution was to use "DirectorySlash Off"
Which i now notice i forgot to add that line into my solution, i shall edit it now for future reference.